# Using JMeter in active directory environment

Tags: proxy, active-directory, jmeter

I am using an machine where active directory is configured. From this machine I am trying to record the JMeter scripts by setting proxy in the browser. But when I try to open the URL, it gives me the Authentication Manager window to enter the username and password. Even when I enter correct credentials, it does not redirect to the website which I want to test.

Am I missing anything?
Is there anything I need to take care of when I am recording the script in Jmeter where AD is configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory authentication isn't something you can effectively record as NTLM headers and Kerberos tokens need to be constructed and the procedure is rather complex.

JMeter provides [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) in order to deal with Basic, NTLM and Kerberos authentication types. For Basic you just need to provide username and password, for NTLM - domain name, for Kerberos - domain name, real name and have proper configuration in `krb5.conf` and `jaas.conf` files which reside in /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for more details and how-to's.