# setting proxy in active directory environment

Tags: proxy, active-directory, jmeter

I am using a machine on which active directory is configured. I am developing an application on the same machine. Now I want to do some performance testing of that application using the JMeter. Now when I start the JMeter proxy server, and set it in browser and try to browse the application I get an error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Am I missing anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JMeter in active directory environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195102/using-jmeter-in-active-directory-environment)